# CameraController and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I'm trying to implement the CWAC2 camera activity in my application to replace the standard camera, but I'm running into the following issue when calling the camera using the following code:

```
    Intent i = new CameraActivity.IntentBuilder(TestActivity.this)
            .skipConfirm()
            .facing(Facing.BACK)
            .facingExactMatch()
            .to(new File(Constants.MEDIA_DIR, "landscape-rear.jpg"))
            .updateMediaStore()
            .flashModes(FLASH_MODES)
            .zoomStyle(ZoomStyle.SEEKBAR)
            .debugSavePreviewFrame()
            .debug()
            .build();
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_PORTRAIT_RFC);
```

And error trace:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: za.co.scsit.i_oncloud, PID: 14419
                  Theme: themes:{com.facebook.orca=overlay:com.cyngn.wileyfox, default=overlay:com.cyngn.wileyfox, iconPack:com.cyngn.wileyfox, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.cyngn.wileyfox, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.cyngn.wileyfox}
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{za.co.scsit.i_oncloud/com.commonsware.cwac.cam2.CameraActivity}: org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.commonsware.cwac.cam2.CameraController and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.commonsware.cwac.cam2.CameraController and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation
                      at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findSubscriberMethods(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:67)
                      at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.register(EventBus.java:136)
                      at com.commonsware.cwac.cam2.CameraController.setEngine(CameraController.java:92)
                      at com.commonsware.cwac.cam2.AbstractCameraActivity.init(AbstractCameraActivity.java:401)
                      at com.commonsware.cwac.cam2.CameraActivity.init(CameraActivity.java:92)
                      at com.commonsware.cwac.cam2.AbstractCameraActivity.onCreate(AbstractCameraActivity.java:252)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Build.Gradle as requested:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'za.co.scsit.i_oncloud'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 21
        versionName "0.10.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.9'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.9'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.3.9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:cam2:0.7.5'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: `CameraController` definitely has methods annotated with `@Subscribe`. See [the source code for 0.7.5, for example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/blob/v0.7.5/cam2/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/cam2/CameraController.java). If you are using ProGuard, [keep the CWAC-Cam2 classes](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2#proguard).

Comment: I'll try upgrade to 0.7.5, seems I'm still running 0.7.4.I did however include the Proguard rule. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Nothing changed between 0.7.4 and 0.7.5 in `CameraController`, IIRC. ProGuard fiddling with my classes is the only thing that I can think of that would result in this specific EventBus error.

Comment: Upgrade didn't seem to change things, still getting the same error. The entirety of my proguard: -keep class com.commonsware.cwac.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.commonsware.cwac.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

Comment: Are you doing a `debug` build, a `release` build, or something else?

Comment: A debug build directly from Android Studio. Haven't tried a release build yet.

Comment: Well, then ProGuard shouldn't be involved anyway, unless you did something funky. Is it possible for you to edit your question and post your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Posted, also tested a release build

Comment: First, before you do much else, I **strongly** recommend that you not use `play-services`, but instead request the specific pieces of Play Services that you need (e.g., `play-services-maps`), as it's unlikely that you need all of Play Services. My hope is that will reduce your app size enough that you can temporarily drop `multidex`, then see if things work with CWAC-Cam2. If you cannot eliminate `multidex`, try moving Cam2 and EventBus [into the primary DEX file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep), and see if that helps.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. I reimported the entire project instead of just the core cam2 and it's working now. I have also taken the dex thing into consideration and stripped away the parts that were causing me to use it in the first place.

Comment: "I reimported the entire project instead of just the core cam2 and it's working now" -- I don't fully understand what you did, but if it is now working, I am grateful.